# orientdb 2.1.11 java process consuming too much memory

Tags: orientdb

We're running OrientDB 2.1.11 (Community Edition) along with JDK 1.8.0.74.

We're noticing memory consumption by 'orientdb' java slowly creeping up and in a few days, the database becomes un-responsive (we have to stop/start Orientdb in order to release memory).
We also noticed this kind of behavior in a few hours when we index the database.
The total size of the database is only 60 GB and not more than 200 million records!

As you can see below, it already consumes VIRT(11.44 GB) RES(8.62 GB).

We're running CentOS 7.1.x.

Even change heap from 512 to 256M and modified diskcache.bufferSize to 8GB
MAXHEAP=-Xmx256m

## ORIENTDB MAXIMUM DISKCACHE IN MB, EXAMPLE, ENTER -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=8192 FOR 8GB

MAXDISKCACHE="-Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=8192"

### top output:

```
Tasks: 155 total,   1 running, 154 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie 
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16269052 total,   229492 free,  9510740 used,  6528820 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  8155244 free,   102288 used.  6463744 avail Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2367 nmx      20   0 11.774g 8.620g  14648 S   0.3 55.6  81:26.82 java
```

### ps aux output:

```
nmx       2367  4.3 55.5 12345680 9038260 ?    Sl   May02  81:28 /bin/java 
-server -Xmx256m -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Drhino.opt.level=9 
-Dprofiler.enabled=true -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=8192
```

How do I control memory usage?
Is there a CB memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

Could you set following setting for JVM -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=2m . 
This should sovle your issue.

Comment: @UPat did you try proposed solution ?

Comment: After bouncing OrientDB we did not encounter issue (looks like during creating index, it consumed more memory which did not get release till server restart.

Answer (score 0):

[this page, solved my issue.](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6922)
in nutshell:
add this configuration to your database:

```
static {
    OGlobalConfiguration.NON_TX_RECORD_UPDATE_SYNCH.setValue(true); //Executes a synch against the file-system at every record operation. This slows down records updates but guarantee reliability on unreliable drives
    OGlobalConfiguration.STORAGE_LOCK_TIMEOUT.setValue(300000);
    OGlobalConfiguration.RID_BAG_EMBEDDED_TO_SBTREEBONSAI_THRESHOLD.setValue(-1);
    OGlobalConfiguration.FILE_LOCK.setValue(false);
    OGlobalConfiguration.SBTREEBONSAI_LINKBAG_CACHE_SIZE.setValue(5000);
    OGlobalConfiguration.INDEX_IGNORE_NULL_VALUES_DEFAULT.setValue(true);
    OGlobalConfiguration.MEMORY_CHUNK_SIZE.setValue(32);
    long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    long maxMemoryGB = (maxMemory / 1024L / 1024L / 1024L);
    maxMemoryGB = maxMemoryGB < 1 ? 1 : maxMemoryGB;
    long cacheSizeMb = 2 * 65536 * maxMemoryGB / 1024;
    long maxDirectMemoryMb =  VM.maxDirectMemory() / 1024L / 1024L;
    String cacheProp = System.getProperty("storage.diskCache.bufferSize");
    if (cacheProp==null) {
        long maxDirectMemoryOrientMb = maxDirectMemoryMb / 3L;
        long cachSizeMb = cacheSizeMb  > maxDirectMemoryOrientMb ? maxDirectMemoryOrientMb : cacheSizeMb;
        cacheSizeMb =  (long)Math.pow(2, Math.ceil( Math.log(cachSizeMb)/ Math.log((2))));
        System.setProperty("storage.diskCache.bufferSize",Long.toString(cacheSizeMb));
        // the command below generates a NullPointerException in Orient 2.2.15-snapshot
        // OGlobalConfiguration.DISK_CACHE_SIZE.setValue(cacheSizeMb);
    }
}
```